# Combine two lists into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two lists at present with a field different in each list one is called payment and the other is called contribution

```
public List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> getUserContributions(Guid _customerInfoId)
    {
        List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules.Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerInfoId && a.isDeleted == false).ToList();

        return _contributions;
    }
```

This is the second list it has a field called date which i want to restrict the first list to less than or equals to but I want to combine both these queries into one list as I am using a repeater to display the info I provide my html as well below in the hope someone can help me combine these two statements into one.

```
public List<tblPortalPayment> getUserPayments(Guid recordId)
    {

        List<tblPortalPayment> _payments = portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(a => a.CustomerId == recordId && a.isDeleted == false).ToList();

        return _payments;

    }
```

Html Code for repeater

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptPayments" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPayments_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>



                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%#Container.ItemIndex %>">

                                        <div class="alert-box notice">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="isinArrears" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("isinArrears") %>' />
                                                <a><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("paymentDate")).ToString("MMMM d  yyyy") %>  </a>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-info-circle"></asp:Label>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>" style="height: auto;">
                                        <div class="panel-body center">

                                            <table id="paymentsummaryhistory">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><strong>Payment Agreed: </strong></td>
                                                        <td><strong>Payment Date:  </strong></td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPaymentDUE" runat="server" Text='<%# "£" + Eval("paymentDue") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                            <br />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                          <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPayemntDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("paymentDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                        </td>


                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>

                                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblArrearsInfo" ClientVisible="False" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isinArrears") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

**Edit 1**

I have modified my query slighty as I only want the top 5 contributions as the 6 payments is in the header record so it is can any one help me out there are two different fields first linq I want paymentDue and second linq I want contribution but I want these combined into one list so can bind to a repeater

```
public List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> getUserContributions(Guid _customerInfoId,DateTime _date)
    {
        List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules.Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerInfoId && a.isDeleted == false && a.DUE_DATE <= _date && a.DUE_DATE !=_date ).Take(5).ToList();

        return _contributions;
    }
```

**Edit 2**

Properties Contribution Schedule
I require Due Date and Contribution from this one
https://snag.gy/PhJgsA.jpg

Properties Payments
I require paymentdue and paymentdate out of this one

https://snag.gy/3wWEjb.jpg

The only values i need out of both are Due Date

Comment: can you show the properties of each list ?

Comment: @Sampath I will once the edit has been approved i cant edit my answer till it is

Comment: can someone please approve edit in this question thanks !

Comment: @Sampath please find ecnlosed my comments and sceen shots of my properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you like this :)

**Note :** please adjust model properties correctly according to your models .

```
var finalResult = _payments.Select(p=>new Payments{ DueDate = p. 
paymentdue}).Concat(_contributions.Select(c=>new Payments{ DueDate = c.dueDate });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok So i got my answer but its very long winded im sure there is a neater way of doing this..

```
public List<Payments> getAllPayemtns(Guid _customerId)

    {
        List<Payments> AllPayments = new List<Payments>();

        List<tblPortalPayment> _payments = portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(a => a.CustomerId == _customerId && a.isDeleted == false).ToList();

        foreach (var payment in _payments)
        {
            AllPayments.Add(new Payments(payment.id, Convert.ToDecimal(payment.paymentDue), Convert.ToDateTime(payment.paymentDate), Convert.ToBoolean(payment.isinArrears));

        }

        List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules.Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerId && a.isDeleted == false && a.DUE_DATE <= _date && a.DUE_DATE != _date).Take(6).OrderByDescending(o => o.DUE_DATE).ToList();
        foreach (var contribution in _contributions)
        {

            AllPayments.Add(new Payments(contribution.ID, Convert.ToDecimal(contribution.Contribution), Convert.ToDateTime(contribution.DUE_DATE), false));

        }

 return AllPayments;
}
```

Then you have payments class as such

```
public class Payments
    {
        public Guid? id { get; set; }
           public Decimal paymentDue { get; set; }
        public DateTime paymentDate { get; set; }
         public bool isinArrears { get; set; }


        public Payments(Guid? id, Decimal paymentDue, DateTime paymentDate, 
         bool isinArrears)
        {
            this.id = id;
             this.paymentDue = paymentDue;
            this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
              this.isinArrears = isinArrears;

        }
}
```

Comment: Some cleanup tips: * you can add constructors to your `Payments` that accept a `tblPortalPayment` or a `tblPortalContributionSchedule`; * LINQ has a `Select` method that you can use to convert from one object to another; * A List has a AddRange method that accepts an entire list; Combined you can have `AllPayments.AddRange(_payments.Select(p => new Payments(p));` instead of the foreach loop.

Comment: @HansKesting can you provide a pusedo code answer so that I may adapat to your approach

Comment: For tip 2 and 3 I already gave an example. For tip 1: next to the existing constructor that accepts parameters for the various properties, add constructors that accept your other classes and get the correct fields form inside that constructor - this cleans up your code a bit. But you could also use the existing constructor with your current code to create a new `Payments` inside the `Select`.